# Regarding the law of Inertia

Tags: inertia

I am still a student in high school, so don't judge me because of this question:-

Imagine you are on a train, then you pass by a tree; for me, this tree appears to me in motion. The train has moved quite a distance and the tree is no longer in sight. So, how will the law of Inertia work on this tree ? (We don't know if the tree is still in motion or not )?

I think that the tree should be in motion as long as the tree is moving, so the law of inertia is not in action in the scenario.... Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: A tree is a poor example, since it is attached to Earth by roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law of Inertia is one of Newton's laws. Newton's laws are assumptions. Given them, motion of objects can be predicted.

We have no reason to expect Newton's laws should be true. We know they are because we have checked and checked and checked.

If you are sitting on a train, the whole world is in motion. You can check on the tree so long as you can see it. When it is out of sight, perhaps a friend in the back of the train can still check. Perhaps you can tie a string to the tree and watch it unwind from a spool. As long as the string is unwinding at the right rate, the tree isn't moving.

After enough checks, you see the pattern and you expect the pattern holds even when you are not checking.

Comment: So are you trying to say that the law is a theory without proof?

Comment: Scientific theories never have proof of correctness. There may be experimental evidence that they are correct. There may be a lot of evidence. But another experiment may uncover a case where the theory doesn't work. This has happened with Newton's laws. Many, many experiments at everyday speeds show they work quite well. But if you try near the speed of light, they don't match what we see. They had to be replaced by the laws of relativity, which work at both low and high speeds.

Comment: See [Falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability)